# jQuery with PHP in Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a jQuery animation into my Wordpress posts.

The animation works fine, but what is hard is how to do it for each individual post. Meaning, each post is assigned a separate ID (e.g. `post-xxxx`) and the only way of knowing the post ID (that I know of) is through Wordpress' `the_ID()` function.

I have my jQuery running in script tags in the index PHP file. How would I go about doing this? My only good idea was to add an `onclick` HTML listener to the `DIV` tag for the post and then use the `this` reference in the jQuery code but it never executed (not sure if my code was wrong).

Here is the code for that thing I tried:

```
<script>
    function('test') {
        $(this).animate({
            height: '+=350'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });

        $('.review-thumb').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    },
</script>
```

With this being my HTML tag:

```
<div onclick="test" class="post number-<?php echo $number; ?> colour-<?php echo $colour; ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

The website theme can be found at http://vusavusa.com/blog/?theme=vusavusa2. Please excuse the messiness of content right now.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this assuming that all the Posts starts with `post-` identifier. The selector below will grab all inputs that has an `id` that starts with `post-`.

```
$('input[id^="post-"]').animate({ height: '+=350' }, { duration: 500 });
```

The concept can be adapted to whatever you're trying to do such as:

```
/** Assign an animation to each element */
$('input[id^="post-"]').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: '+=350' }, { duration: 500 });
    return false;
});
```

Another option is to use `slideToggle` to animate to expand your `Post` into a full view. your full view will be preloaded but is hidden by default and will have a class of `post-full`.

**CSS:**

```
.post-full { display: none; }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() { 
    $('[id^="post-"]').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.post-full').slideToggle(500, function(){});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! I tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything. I have it live right now on my website link, so you can see.

Comment: You need to remove that `onclick="test"` and add what I have above somewhere you your JS file.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that too. I did that, and your code is in the website. Line 430 on page source.

Comment: Well I'll be damned... I didn't realize jQuery could target elements that way. +1 for you, good sir.

Comment: Anything more to add anyone?

Comment: What's the direct URL to your JS file?

Comment: You need to wrap that code with `$(function() { /** The code goes here*/  });`

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're trying to do. Are you doing something like this? http://jsbin.com/afegom/1/edit . You can use slideToggle to animate your hidden `div`. Check out the quick JSBin that I've made and see if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, you've got it right on. And that actually reminds me - display:none; is a much better use than toggling the opacity. Thanks for that find.

Comment: Ok look at my website again. I've got it sort of working with your codee. Animation isn't exactly what I want, but that's easy to change.

Comment: The problem is that it's applying to every div even when I just click on one. THat's been the main issue.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to use `$(this).find('.post-full').slideToggle(500, function(){});` to make sure that only the specific post full is animated as oppose to all `.post-full`

Comment: Ok when I add in the .find method, it doesn't work at all. When I take it out, it does all of them. I replaced '.post-full' with '.post_content' which is what I set for the class around Wordpress' the_content() function. Here's the PHP code, to make sure I'm doing it right. .post_content is set to display: none;

Comment: We need to discuss this in a chat but since you're brand new to Stack Overflow, send me an email by going to my website so I can further help you.

Comment: Your code needs to be `$(this).find('.post_content').slideToggle(500, function(){});`. Find that line and replace it with what I have here and that fixes it. Just copy and paste it.

Comment: Oh. Silly me. I left the "." off the the class tag. Now before I go and mess everything up should it be pretty basic to replace .slideToggle with .animate so I can cause the div to expand with it?

Comment: Seems that just setting the divs to min-height does the trick with the div expanding. Might need to do more animating though. Thanks a ton so far though!!!

Comment: Please mark the answer if this answers your question. Feel free to create a new question if you get stuck again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a class (e.g. "postClass") and use
`$('.postClass')`

Comment: Then every box would animate when you click just one of them.